# DevOps migrate prepare fails after 'user not found' graph call

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to migrate on-premise TFS (DevOps Server 2019 update 1.1) to DevOps Services and using the [migrate tool](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/devops/migrate/). I have run the `validate` command and cleaned up those warnings but the next command (`prepare`) fails mysteriously. The log file simply says:

```
[Error  @11:18:19.488] 
    Exception Message: Request failed (type AadGraphTimeoutException)
    Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.DataImport.AadIdentityMapper.ExecuteGraphRequest[T](Func`1 request)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.DataImport.AadIdentityMapper.GetAadTenantId()
       at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.PopulateDataImportPropertiesOnContext()
       at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.PopulateValidationItems(DataImportValidationContext context)
       at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandValidate.RunValidations(Boolean validateFiles)
       at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommandPrepare.RunImpl()
       at TfsMigrator.TfsMigratorCommand.Run()
```

A colleague pointed out [this troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-troubleshooting?view=azure-devops#azure-active-directory-timeout-exception) from the docs but a) we have about 10 users involved in TFS (~50 total active in local AD) so it is hard to believe we have so many users it would time out, and b) I ran the `Get-MsolUser` troubleshooting commands and successfully queried AAD via Graph.

I ran the `prepare` command again with Fiddler Classic connected as a proxy and discovered a failing call to the Graph API. It looked like

Request (simplified headers):

```
POST https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0664e34adcbd/$batch?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_ea471df4-db73-403d-a172-a0955ddb1575
...

--batch_ea471df4-db73-403d-a172-a0955ddb1575
GET https://graph.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0664e34adcbd/tenantDetails?api-version=1.6 HTTP/1.1
...

--batch_ea471df4-db73-403d-a172-a0955ddb1575--
```

Response (body):

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_Unauthorized",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "User was not found."
        },
        "requestId": "58c4cabc-dd67-4ce8-9735-134a7e0df60c",
        "date": "2020-09-14T20:07:49"
    }
}
```

So my question at this point is - Are there any permissions (DevOps, Azure, Graph) that are missing? Are there any work arounds available? I did tag this question with Microsoft Graph API but do believe the failing call uses the older Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: 1. What permissions did you add? Is it convenient to provide screenshots? Go to AAD>App registrations>API permissions to provide a screenshot, 2. How did you request the token? Please provide your code, we will use it for troubleshooting.

Comment: This is a Microsoft-built OTS application and it did not instruct me to register it in our tenant. I can provide the Fiddler traces for the token request but again, this is a black box - not code we wrote.

Comment: Here's one [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/338522/tfs-migration-request-failed-type-aadgraphtimeoute.html) like yours, maybe you need to modify the proxy details in machine.config file like what *Niel* did.

Comment: Yes @PodMo I found that link prior to posting but didn't mention it because we are not using a proxy.

Comment: See `Run a network trace while executing the prepare command to ensure that nothing within your network is interfering with calls reaching Azure AD. ` Have you made sure the network is ok?